# I have a google script that creates QR codes and Barcode. the QR Codes show up twice. Once where its suppose to and then at the end of the document

Tags: image, google-apps-script, qr-code, barcode

The code below generates a label that has a QR Code and barcode.  Currently I am trying to get both to work.  They both show up in the label but when it does the QR code will be added in the correct spot but also will add extra qr codes on the last label generated. The two qr codes at the end are itemnum qr codes and they are not suppose to be there.  It normally puts them ontop of each other i moved them so people could see.    The barcodes generate just fine but they don't scan

[TEST SCRIPT](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6o05Sa-x9uhwj2WrLydPzhbcEBD2pkGJ-BRAS0LtoI/edit?usp=sharing) here is a link to test it.. This is a test script and not part of a business so its easy to do. Basically what needs done is click on My Custom Menu and select reset labels. Once the labels are created you can go to the labels tab and select a few labels with serial numbers then go back to the menu and select create labels for selected items.

[image]

//#######################################     Create Zebra Label #########################

```
function createZebraLabel(monthlySheet, newSheetName) {

    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1mUPLw1PSi-guH19uJPCPWmogkpdckLcW');
    var createdoc = DocumentApp.create('Zebra Label').getId();
    doc = DocumentApp.openById(createdoc);

    var id = createdoc;
    var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());

    var target = parentFolder;
    var file1 = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    var mkfile1 = file1.makeCopy(newSheetName, target).getId();
    doc = DocumentApp.openById(mkfile1);
    docFile.setTrashed(true);
    //325
    var body = doc.getBody().setPageWidth(325).setPageHeight(180).setMarginTop(.2).setMarginBottom(.2);
    //  var body = doc.getBody().setPageWidth(144).setPageHeight(144).setMarginTop(.2).setMarginBottom(.2);


    var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(monthlySheet);
    var ss = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

    var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 250; // Number of rows to process
    var startColumn = 1;  // A=1 B=2
    var numColumns = 5;  // Number of columns to process
    var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var actualrow = i;

        var itemnum = row[0]; // A column
        var desc = row[1]; // B column
        var serial = row[2]; // D column
        var bin = row[3]; // D column
        var qty = row[4];


        var styleLeft = {};
        styleLeft[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
        styleLeft[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
        styleLeft[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
        styleLeft[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

        var styleRight = {};
        styleRight[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
        styleRight[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
        styleRight[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
        styleRight[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;


        var itemBarcode = {};
        itemBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
        itemBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text';
        itemBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 25;
        itemBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;

        var serialBarcode = {};
        serialBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
        serialBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text';
        serialBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 20;
        serialBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;

        var nospace = {};
        nospace[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
        nospace[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
        nospace[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 1;
        nospace[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
        var text = body.editAsText();


        var itemqrcode = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=70x70&cht=qr&chl=' + itemnum);
        var serialqrcode = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=70x70&cht=qr&chl=' + serial);
        if (itemnum != '') {
            //####################   SERIAL  ###################     
            if (serial != '') {  // SERIAL NUMBER


                body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace);
                var paragraph = body.appendParagraph('Item Number: ' + itemnum).setAttributes(styleLeft);
                paragraph.addPositionedImage(itemqrcode.getBlob()).setLayout(DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.WRAP_TEXT)
                body.appendParagraph('*' + itemnum + '*').setAttributes(itemBarcode);
                body.appendParagraph('\n\n').setAttributes(nospace).appendHorizontalRule();

                //description
                body.appendParagraph(desc).setAttributes(styleLeft);
                body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace);

                //serials
                body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace).appendHorizontalRule();

                var paragraph = body.appendParagraph('Serial Number:  ' + serial).setAttributes(styleRight);
                body.appendParagraph('*' + serial + '*').setAttributes(serialBarcode);
                paragraph.addPositionedImage(serialqrcode.getBlob()).setLayout(DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.WRAP_TEXT)

                body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace);



            } else if (serial == '') { // NO SERIAL NUMBER
                var styleCenter = {};
                styleCenter[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
                styleCenter[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
                styleCenter[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
                styleCenter[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

                var itemBarcode = {};
                itemBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
                itemBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text';
                itemBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 35;
                itemBarcode[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;

                var styleLocation = {};
                styleLocation[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
                styleLocation[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
                styleLocation[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
                styleLocation[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

                body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace);
                var paragraph = body.appendParagraph('Item Number: ' + itemnum).setAttributes(styleLeft);
                body.appendParagraph('*' + itemnum + '*').setAttributes(itemBarcode);
                body.appendParagraph('\n').setAttributes(nospace).appendHorizontalRule();


                //description
                body.appendParagraph(desc).setAttributes(styleLeft);
                body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace).appendHorizontalRule();
                body.appendParagraph('Location: ' + bin + '        Qty: ' + qty).setAttributes(styleLocation);
                body.appendParagraph('\n').setAttributes(nospace);
            }
            body.appendPageBreak();


        }
    }


    var googledoc = doc.getUrl();
    FinishedGoogleDoc(googledoc);
}
```

Below is my solution that does work.

/

```
/#######################################     Create Zebra Label #########################

function createZebraLabel(monthlySheet,newSheetName){

var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1mUPLw1PSi-guH19uJPCPWmogkpdckLcW');
var createdoc = DocumentApp.create('Zebra Label').getId();
doc = DocumentApp.openById(createdoc);

var id = createdoc;
var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());

var target = parentFolder;
var file1 = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
var mkfile1 = file1.makeCopy(newSheetName, target).getId();
doc = DocumentApp.openById(mkfile1);
docFile.setTrashed(true);
//325
var body = doc.getBody().setPageWidth(325).setPageHeight(180).setMarginTop(.02).setMarginBottom(.02);
//  var body = doc.getBody().setPageWidth(144).setPageHeight(200).setMarginTop(.01).setMarginBottom(.01);


  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(monthlySheet);
  var ss = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 

  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 250; // Number of rows to process
  var startColumn = 1;  // A=1 B=2
  var numColumns = 5;  // Number of columns to process
  var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var actualrow=i;

    var itemnum = row[0]; // A column
    var desc = row[1]; // B column
    var serial = row[2]; // D column
    var bin = row[3]; // D column
    var qty =row[4];

 if (itemnum != ''){  

    var styleITEMNUM = {};
styleITEMNUM[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;   
styleITEMNUM[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] =DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
styleITEMNUM[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
styleITEMNUM[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
styleITEMNUM[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

     var styleDESC = {};
styleDESC[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
styleDESC[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
styleDESC[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 10;
styleDESC[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;


        var styleSERIAL = {};
styleSERIAL[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
styleSERIAL[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] =DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
styleSERIAL[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
styleSERIAL[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
styleSERIAL[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

      var nospace = {};
nospace[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
nospace[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
nospace[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] =-1;
nospace[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
     var text = body.editAsText();

 var paraStyle = {};
  paraStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_BOTTOM] = 0;
   paraStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_TOP] = 0;
  paraStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_TOP] = 0;
  paraStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = 0;
  paraStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_AFTER] = 0;
  paraStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 0;


    var itemqrcode = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=80x80&cht=qr&chl='+itemnum);
    var serialqrcode = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=80x80&cht=qr&chl='+serial);

//####################  ITEM WITH SERIAL NUMBER ###################     
   if (itemnum != '' && serial != ''){  // SERIAL NUMBE

body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace);      
var table = body.appendTable().setBorderWidth(0).setAttributes(paraStyle);
var tr = table.appendTableRow().setAttributes(paraStyle);
var td = tr.appendTableCell('').setWidth(80).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0).appendImage(itemqrcode.getBlob()).setAttributes(paraStyle);
var td = tr.appendTableCell('Item Number\n' +itemnum).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0).setAttributes(styleITEMNUM);

body.appendHorizontalRule().setAttributes(nospace);
body.appendParagraph(desc).setAttributes(styleDESC);
body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace).appendHorizontalRule().setAttributes(nospace);
body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace);       
var table = body.appendTable().setBorderWidth(0).setAttributes(paraStyle);
var tr = table.appendTableRow().setAttributes(paraStyle);
var td = tr.appendTableCell('').setWidth(80).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0).appendImage(serialqrcode.getBlob()).setHeight(80);
var td = tr.appendTableCell('Serial Number\n ' +serial).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0).setAttributes(styleSERIAL);

 }
 else if (itemnum != '' && serial == ''){ // NO SERIAL NUMBER

var styleLocation = {};
styleLocation[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
styleLocation[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
styleLocation[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] =12;
styleLocation[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace);      
var table = body.appendTable().setBorderWidth(0).setAttributes(paraStyle);
var tr = table.appendTableRow().setAttributes(paraStyle);
var td = tr.appendTableCell('').setWidth(80).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0).appendImage(itemqrcode.getBlob()).setAttributes(paraStyle);
var td=tr.appendTableCell('Item Number\n' +itemnum).setAttributes(styleITEMNUM);
     body.appendParagraph('\n').setAttributes(nospace).appendHorizontalRule();
body.appendParagraph(desc).setAttributes(styleDESC);
body.appendParagraph('\n').setAttributes(nospace).appendHorizontalRule();
body.appendParagraph('').setAttributes(nospace);      

var table = body.appendTable().setBorderWidth(0).setAttributes(paraStyle);
var tr = table.appendTableRow().setAttributes(paraStyle);
var td=tr.appendTableCell('Location:'+bin).setWidth(200).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0).setAttributes(styleLocation);
var td=tr.appendTableCell('Qty: ' +qty).setAttributes(styleLocation);

    }
      body.appendPageBreak();

   }
  }    

 var googledoc = doc.getUrl();
 FinishedGoogleDoc(googledoc);


  }
```

Comment: Is the top picture the expected and the bottom picture the actual? Just trying to clear up what you are expecting the end result to look like. I only ask because the top picture seems to be correct, I want to make sure it's just an edited version (or something like that) from you. And it's not the code somehow generating a correct one sometimes.

Comment: I do want it to look like the top label but that is acutally what it does.. the script will create the label correctly for the first labels but on the very last was it adds all of the qr labels at the bottom ontop of each other.  It acts like t loops through twice but I cant see where it actually does.

Comment: Ah so it's just the very last label. You should probably clarify your situation in the question as details like that are important for debugging the code. Especially when we can't really run it ourselves.

Comment: thanks I did.  And I could give access if needed.

Comment: Giving people as much ability to actually try out your code (or a version of it) is always super helpful. As long as your are careful not to expose any business/sensitive code. Remember that anything you post here is completely public.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6o05Sa-x9uhwj2WrLydPzhbcEBD2pkGJ-BRAS0LtoI/edit?usp=sharing  here is a link to test it..  This is a test script and not part of a business so its easy to do.  Basically what needs done is click on My Custom Menu and select reset labels.  Once the labels are created you can go to the labels tab and select a few labels with serial numbers then go back to the menu and select create labels for selected items.

Comment: Awesome! Put those details in the question as well though :D Also you can't run those scripts in the menu without permissions. So maybe make a copy you don't care if someone destroys and open up the permissions for those scripts

Comment: This is actually a test script so I dont care about the data in it..

Comment: Hi there @JeremyLarson! I don’t fully understand the issue, could you please clarificate it for me? I assume that you want a result like the first pic, but you are getting results like the second one. Is that a correct assumption? Reading your code I see a lot of different functions, could you identify which one has a problematic behaviour?

Comment: The function is createZebraLabel.  The qr codes are suppose to suppose to display like they do on the top label and they do.  But on the very last label it puts all of the item qr codes at the very bottom on top of each other.  Kinda acting like it reruns the loop but it doesnt..

Comment: I have tried to execute your code but is not working for me. Could you maybe prepare a simple setup for reproduce your problem? The menu item you mention does not appear for me.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually found a solution

Comment: Thanks.  I actually found a solution.  Basically what I found that using addPositionedImage causes this issue and when I use appendImage it works the way I want it to

Comment: Could you maybe post your solution as an answer so other people can reproduce it. Take a look at [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).